# Bottom line in SVG image is missing

Tags: svg

I am new to SVG and I am trying to get a better understanding of the SVG attributes. 
For this problem, I am trying to understand why the bottom line can't appear. I think it has something to do with viewBox, but i can't seem to get it right. It looks like there is a restriction within a fixed view (width and height) so that when it crosses the fixed width and height it will not display the shapes. How can I extent the width and height? I tried changing the percentages but that isn't correct either.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50%" height="50%" >

<!--1st row-->
    <svg viewBox="-10 -10 2700 2700">
      <!--  box outline -->
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="900" height="900" stroke="black" fill="rgb(255,255,255)"
        fill-opacity="0" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width = "10"/>
  <!-- OBJECT SHAPE -->
      <!-- row wise [first row -circle ]-->
      <circle cx="450" cy="150" r="30" stroke="black" fill-opacity="0"  stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width = "3" />
    </svg>

    <svg viewBox="-960 -10 2700 2700">
      <!--  box outline -->
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="900" height="900" stroke="black" fill="rgb(255,255,255)"
        fill-opacity="0" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width = "10"/>
  <!-- OBJECT SHAPE -->
      <!-- row wise [first row -circle ]-->
      <circle cx="750" cy="750" r="50" stroke="black" fill-opacity="0"  stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width = "3" />
    </svg>

    <svg viewBox="-1930 -10 2700 2700">
        <!--  box outline -->
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="900" height="900" stroke="black" fill="rgb(255,255,255)"
          fill-opacity="0" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width = "10"/>
    <!-- OBJECT SHAPE -->
        <!-- row wise [first row -circle ]-->
        <circle cx="450" cy="450" r="70" stroke="black" fill-opacity="0"  stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width = "3" />
      </svg>

<!--2nd row-->
    <svg viewBox="-10 -950 2700 2700">
      <!--  box outline -->
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="900" height="900" stroke="black" fill="rgb(255,255,255)"
        fill-opacity="0" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width = "10"/>
  <!-- OBJECT SHAPE -->
      <!-- row wise [first row -circle ]-->
      <circle cx="450" cy="150" r="30" stroke="black" fill-opacity="0"  stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width = "3" />
    </svg>

    <svg viewBox="-960 -950 2700 2700">
      <!--  box outline -->
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="900" height="900" stroke="black" fill="rgb(255,255,255)"
        fill-opacity="0" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width = "10"/>
  <!-- OBJECT SHAPE -->
      <!-- row wise [first row -circle ]-->
      <circle cx="750" cy="750" r="50" stroke="black" fill-opacity="0"  stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width = "3" />
    </svg>


    <svg viewBox="-1920 -950 2700 2700">
        <!--  box outline -->
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="900" height="900" stroke="black" fill="rgb(255,255,255)"
          fill-opacity="0" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width = "10"/>
    <!-- OBJECT SHAPE -->
        <!-- row wise [first row -circle ]-->
        <circle cx="450" cy="450" r="70" stroke="black" fill-opacity="0"  stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width = "3" />
      </svg>

<!--3rd row-->
    <svg viewBox="-10 -1900 2700 2700">
      <!--  box outline -->
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="900" height="900" stroke="black" fill="rgb(255,255,255)"
        fill-opacity="0" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width = "10"/>
  <!-- OBJECT SHAPE -->
      <!-- row wise [first row -circle ]-->
      <circle cx="450" cy="150" r="30" stroke="black" fill-opacity="0"  stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width = "3" />
    </svg>

    <svg viewBox="-960 -1900 2700 2700">
      <!--  box outline -->
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="900" height="900" stroke="black" fill="rgb(255,255,255)"
        fill-opacity="0" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width = "10"/>
  <!-- OBJECT SHAPE -->
      <!-- row wise [first row -circle ]-->
      <circle cx="750" cy="750" r="50" stroke="black" fill-opacity="0"  stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width = "3" />
    </svg>

<svg viewBox="-1920 -1900 2700 2700">
    <!--  box outline -->
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="900" height="900" stroke="black" fill="rgb(255,255,255)"
      fill-opacity="0" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width = "10"/>
<!-- OBJECT SHAPE -->
    <!-- row wise [first row -circle ]-->
    <circle cx="450" cy="450" r="70" stroke="black" fill-opacity="0"  stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width = "3" />
  </svg>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at one of the bottom row viewBoxes.

```
viewBox="-1920 -1900 2700 2700"
```

So this says the visible drawing will be y values from y=-1900 to y=2700-1900=800

The rect goes from y=0 to y=900 so the bottom of it is outside the viewBox and you see it clipped off.